# Inverse Quaternion Rotation 3D Animation

Tags: matlab, 3d, rotation, quaternions

I am currently developing a code that allows the rotation of a 3D sphere using MATLAB's GUIDE.

The method used is using quaternions, and it works fine actually. The issue is the reverse rotation, where a sphere rotates one direction but when pressing a button in the UI, it reverses direction. From many online sources, it says that the inverse rotation of a quaternion is equal to negating the vector terms and dividing both scalar and vector terms by the magnitude. Implementing this into the MATLAB code, the sphere does not smoothly transition and rotate.

I've tested SLERP and LERP methods but that warps the sphere

Does anyone know if this is the correct methodology, or what would be?

Thanks in advance, 
Tony

Comment: If your program is rotating the sphere properly using quaternion Q = [w,x,y,z], then as you say the reverse rotation is Q* = [w, -x, -y, -z] assuming that Q is a unit quaternion it will not be necessary to normalise Q*.
Can you provide some more details? Is it jumping from Q to Q* immediately? Why does S/LERP not work?

Comment: Yes, I have applied that but it does not applied smoothly.  When using SLERP the sphere warps from a unit sphere to a non-spherical shape and back, its very weird.  What I want is go from Q1 -> Q2 and then back to Q1 smoothly, but negating the vector coefficients do not work.

Comment: How are you rotating the sphere? I have a feeling the sphere's centre is offset from the global origin, and you are rotating the sphere around the global frame instead of around the sphere's centre.

Comment: There is no code that offsets the sphere from the centre, unless its default location is not at the global origin?  It is rotated by applying a 4x4 rotation matrix R to hgrotate.